# SSL issue after resetting DNS

Tags: wordpress, ssl, lets-encrypt, insecure-connection

Earlier our website was working fine. We had SSL certificates from lets-encrypt. Due to some issue I had to remove the DNS servers from godaddy.
Now I have added the same DNS servers in godaddy. Though the site works fine. But firts throws on the page with `Your connection is not secure` error.
Here is what I get:

`The owner of duskylory.store has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.`

Do I have to reissue the cerficates from let-sencrypt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've connected to your site and it says that your certificate has expired 4 days ago. You have to reissue the certificates from Let's Encrypt to get rid of this warning.